# Column not found error while trying to mass assign values inside controller

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.5, mass-assignment

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to assign a value to all the columns in a table.

**Controller**

```php
public function updateallcompany(Request $request, $id)
{
    $active = $request->input('active');
    AccessCode::where('company_id', $id)->update([$active, 'active']);

    return view('pages.accesscode.showallaccesscodecompany')
        ->with('success', "AccessCodes Updated");
}
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field 
>     list' (SQL: update `access_codes` set `0` = Yes, `1` = active, `updated_at` = 2019-04-11 11:10:03 where `company_id` = 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the `$active` value to the field `active`.

You can see `Mass Updates` example on laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Try:

```
 AccessCode::where('company_id', $id)->update(['active' => $active]);
```